# How to create shipment using rest api in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, shipment

How we can create shipment of a order using rest api.

Comment: Check this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-shipment.html

Comment: can you tell me the parameters for json that need to be send?

Comment: Please check below link to create the shipment using rest API : https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-create-shipment-using-rest-api-magento-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have researched on this and found an answer.

**URL** : http://domain/rest/V1/order/237/ship     -:-   where 237 is the order id

**Method**: post

**Input Parameters** :

```
{
   "items": [
     {
       "order_item_id": 623,
       "qty": 1
     }
   ],
   "notify": true,
  "appendComment": true,
   "comment": {
    "extension_attributes": {},
    "comment": "comment on shipment",
    "is_visible_on_front": 1
   },
   "tracks": [
     {
       "track_number": "123456",
       "title": "fedex Shipment",
       "carrier_code": "fedex"
     }
   ]
}
```

This will create shipment and notify the customer also.

Answer (score 2):

**Api Link : {base_url}/index.php/rest/default/V1/order/291/ship**
Order ID and increment ID is not same

Here 291 is order_id **not** a Increment Id

Sample Body:

```
{

"items": [

   {
     "order_item_id": 2448,
     "qty": 1
   },
   {
     "order_item_id": 2449,
     "qty": 1
   }
]

}
```

You can get "order_item_id" from fetching order info through API. Hope it helps !!

Comment: so 2448 should be simple or configurable product id if we use configurable products.

Answer (score 1):

If you have configurable products, please use simple item’s parent_item_id field.
It is unique id even the simple product is under same configurable product.

item_id": 1518,
"name": "IVORY LONGLINE TEE S",
"no_discount": 0,
"order_id": 534,
"original_price": 0,
"**parent_item_id": 1515,**

Thanks

Comment: WOW, totally insane! Why it's like that? Of course not blaming you but Magento developers...